# Flutter is unable to find bundled Java Version

Tags: java, android, flutter

When running "flutter doctor", I get this:

[flutter doctor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTajJ.png)

Tried installing [Java SE Development kit](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/jdk15-archive-downloads.html) with Windows x64 Installer, because I'm on Windows 10, then added the following env variable:[environment variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FiC71.png)

Also, saw people suggesting to paste jbr folder's content into jre folder in Android Studio folder, but this is how it looks like for me: [Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BNrN.png)